# How do I make a plot that changes through time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Now, here is the code I'm working with:

```
import numpy                       
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt     
import time, sys                   

nx = 41  
dx = 2 / (nx-1)
nt = 25    
dt = 0.025
c = 1      
fig = plt.figure()

u = numpy.ones(nx)    
u[int(.5 / dx):int(1 / dx + 1)] = 2  
print(u)


un = numpy.ones(nx)

for n in range(nt):
    un = u.copy()
    plt.plot(numpy.linspace(0, 2, nx), u)
    for i in range(1, nx):
        u[i] = un[i] - c*dt/dx * (un[i] - un[i - 1])

plt.show()
```

It should animate the solution to the equation ∂u/∂t + c * ∂u/∂x = 0; but I don't know how to animate it - because at the current state, it shows at once the function at all time steps; and if instead I put `plt.show()` inside the loop (the outer one), it shows the graphs one at a time, and I have to close the graph window to see the next, which is not very convenient.

Comment: Try using Jupyter Notebook or Colab. There you can achieve what you want if you use plt.show() in outer cycle and clear cell output before showing the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) can be used to [create animations](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/animation_api.html).

The code of the post can be rendered as an animation as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

nx = 41
dx = 2 / (nx-1)
nt = 25
dt = 0.025
c = 1
fig = plt.figure()

u = np.ones(nx)
u[int(.5 / dx):int(1 / dx + 1)] = 2

x = np.linspace(0, 2, nx)

plot1, = plt.plot(x, u)

def update(t):
    un = u.copy()
    for i in range(1, nx):
        u[i] = un[i] - c*dt/dx * (un[i] - un[i - 1])
    plot1.set_ydata(u)
    return plot1,

FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=nt, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

PS: Note the comma after `plot1` in `plot1, = plt.plot(...`. This grabs the first element in the list returned by `plt.plot`.

Comment: It works, thanks! But I don't understand what is that plot1 = plot1[0]

Comment: In older versions of matplotlib [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) returned just one `Line2D` object. Current versions always return a list of them, even if that list only contains one object. To get just that one object, `plot1 = plot1[0]` is used.

Comment: I just noticed that you can also write `plot1, = plt.plot` to directly get the first element in the list. One strange line less, one strange comma more...

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as a gif using the following:

```
import numpy                       
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt     
import time, sys   
from celluloid import Camera
from IPython.display import Image

nx = 41  
dx = 2 / (nx-1)
nt = 25    
dt = 0.025
c = 1      
fig = plt.figure()

u = numpy.ones(nx)    
u[int(.5 / dx):int(1 / dx + 1)] = 2  
print(u)


un = numpy.ones(nx)
fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
for n in range(nt):
    un = u.copy()
    plt.plot(numpy.linspace(0, 2, nx), u, color= "blue")
    for i in range(1, nx):
        u[i] = un[i] - c*dt/dx * (un[i] - un[i - 1])
    camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate()
animation.save('solution.gif', writer = 'imagemagick')
```

In essence it recursively takes a camera "snap" for each dt and collates them into a gif saved as "solution.gif" in the current working directory.